# Still show search results when editing the title of a question, even if "that's not a very good title"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, asking-questions

Typing the same words into the search bar and the "title" field when editing a question lead to different results. The title field relies only on the title of the question, where as the search bar takes into account content of the question too. Seeing as they're not the same, something I want to use the title-field method, but it won't show me the search results unless I have a "good title"

Since the title bar has a different search method, people are going to want to use it to search questions. Especially when someone's asking a question and they don't want to use the search bar and have to load a new page for every new search.

**It says, "you don't have a good title, so we won't show you any similar questions or help you find what you're looking for".**

I completely agree with the message saying its not a good title for a question, I just think the search results should be displayed anyways. :D

Answer (score 2):

Declined, I think adding an intitle:1 advanced search option makes way more sense than this.

intitle:1 is now active.

Comment: Agreed, but if `intitle:1` will take 6-8 weeks but implementing CrazyJugglerDrummer's suggestion is a one-liner, please consider implementing this anyway.

Comment: so now I have to go to a completely different part of the page and loose the benefit of not having to reload the page every time I have a new search query...